# JUnit4: How to verify that a variable name is correct

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm new to JUnit and I'm trying to set up automatic grading for a course I'm developing.

I want to make sure that students are using the following variable names:

```
firstName3, firstName2, firstName1
```

In that order once they include it in a pretty standard `System.out.println();` line in a `Main` class and `main` method.

How can I test for that in JUnit?

Comment: Do you want to test that code has this line `System.out.println(firstName3, firstName2, firstName1);`?

Comment: Usually, one uses unit tests to verify *behaviour*.  Why is it important what internal (?) variable names are used?  (Which is really very hard to test.)

Comment: JUnit tests behavior, not code quality or style. (I'd even argue that names with a trailing number are poor style.)

Comment: @Ivan yes, exactly

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm trying to set up a basic lesson on Scanner and one of the things I want students to do is take in first names in order and then reverse them in an output.  Basic, I know - but a foundation step into collection type variables.

Comment: I see.  As I say, if the code itself is the important thing (rather than just the behaviour) JUnit might not be the best tool for this.  Though I'm not sure I have any bright ideas on alternative tools that would achieve want you want :/

Comment: @Robert Are you saying JUnit can't do that sort of thing?

Comment: @mpcsf JUnit is just plain old Java code that invokes your code, and helps you to check the returned values and/or exceptions thrown. If you can't tell the names of the variables when you invoke it, JUnit can't either.

Comment: @AndyTurner got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the other non-answers: you are looking at the wrong aspect.

You can use tests to verify the observable behavior of the code the students write. Your test drives a specific input, and expects specific output.

That should be your first priority.

Beyond that, there is really (not much) sense in verifying that student code has a specific structure. Even when you use a java source parser, there will be zillions of ways to correctly solve the assignment that doesn't have the (exact) structure you are expecting. Maybe one of your students got really bored about typing name1, name2, name3, and he figures "there are arrays for such stuff" himself, and uses that in his solution. Would you want to punish him for that?!

Thus you should solve this part of the problem where it belongs: on the meta/social level.

In other words: find a good way for students to sit together and review their code. You could ask for a volunteer and present his work in class, and then talk about pros and cons. Or you establish small groups, and have a more experienced person work as tutor.

Not every "technical" problem must be addressed with technical solutions!

Comment: I agree with your classroom approach to this particular problem as a whole.

Comment: I agree with your classroom approach to this particular problem as a whole.  

However, know that arrays/collections/lists haven't been covered yet in class.  While I'd never punish a student for working on something "ahead" of the class, they're still working on syntax and primitives - I only am including Strings because it's easy for students who are just starting to use words as values. 

In addition to that, students are in remote areas working at their own pace.  I'm incorporating GitHub and other collaborative tools, but I have to allow students to get immediate technical feedback.

Comment: @mpcsf But then the question is if file+compiler+class files is really what you want. Wouldnt it be more helpful then to give the students a web front end where they only have to put down *parts* of methods? Like the stuff that should go into the main method? As said: when structure matters to you, looking at class file behavior is not going to help you much.

Answer (score 0):

It was answered by @andy-turner in comments above. What I'm looking for cannot be done by JUnit.

> JUnit is just plain old Java code that invokes your code, and helps
>   you to check the returned values and/or exceptions thrown. If you
>   can't tell the names of the variables when you invoke it, JUnit can't
>   either. – Andy Turner

Comment: If you insist on automating checks like that, you could take a look at libraries like [JavaParser](http://javaparser.org/), which provide functionality for parsing and inspecting java source code.